# Redux in React Native without React Navigation state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I saw [Redux Integration page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) on React Navigation website but I do not understand why we need to store navigation state inside Redux store, can't we just store our application's state with Redux and letting navigator keep its own state?

Because it seems very complicated to integrate  `router.getStateForAction()` and `router.getActionForPathAndParams()`.

- I have questions in my mind like should we use `getStateForAction()` for every screen name we have? Create a reducer for them each?
- Should we do the same for nested screens inside other navigators within the root navigator?
- When should we use `router.getActionForPathAndParams()` then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not necessary to store navigation state in reducer. If you don’t need that just keep the app state in reducer and navigation state on its own. Then you can integrate Redux like this:

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import RootNavigator from './src/navigation/RootNavigation';
import configureStore from './src/stores/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

But actually, it’s not so complex to integrate navigation state within Redux. And if you do that the navigation state will be automatically updated when you navigate between screens. It so helpful in the complex apps. So, I will just try to explain to you how to use React Navigation and Redux together, maybe you will find it useful in future.

First of all, you configure your StackNavigator [as usual](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/quick-start#Creating-a-StackNavigator):

```
// navigation/RootNavigator.js

const HomeScreen = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home Screen</Text>
  </View>
);

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});

export default RootNavigator;
```

Then you go to `reducers` folder (if you have one) and create navReducer.js

```
 // reducers/navReducer.js

import RootNavigator from '../navigation/RootNavigation';

const initialState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(RootNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Home'));

const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
};
```

Where we use `RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction` just to get navigation state and set it as an initial state of new reducer.

Then combine the reducer with others:

```
// reducers/index.js

Import navReducer from ‘./navReducer’;

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,// updated was nav:nav,
  ...
});
```

Now we just need to modify our `App.js`. Now it will looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import RootNavigator from './src/navigation/RootNavigation';
import configureStore from './src/stores/configureStore';
const store = configureStore();

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.navReducer
});

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(AppComponent);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

So, you don’t need to wrap each component with `addNavigationHelpers`, just root component. You don’t need to send/manage actions when navigating between screens. It will be automatically updated.

Comment: Still heaving my head wrapped around it and trying to make sense, some key points I missed was every nested navigator needs to get navigationHelpers, needs to be wrapped with "connect()", needs to have a reducer and needs to get state passed into its props. I thought only the top level navigator needs that. Second point, I checked the sample react navigation redux project at their github but it had lots of logic in their reducers, I thought I had to reduce nav data by the action myself but simple but router.getStateForAction() is doing that automatically. Still checking, gotta sleep now!

Comment: You don’t need to wrap each component with `addNavigationHelpers`, just root component. You don’t need to send/manage actions when navigating between screens. It will be automatically updated. And as I said it’s not necessary to store navigation state in reducer. So if your app is simple and you don’t need that extra logic - just use my first example.

Comment: Not each component, but each navigator... Are you sure each navigator under root navigator shouldn't be wrapper with addNavigationHelpers?

Comment: Truth to be said I have no experience with combining navigators. You can always create a question about that. I am pretty sure if you create a question about combining react navigators and storing their states in Redux you will find an answer! But if we back to our topic, yes, it's possible to use redux without storing navigation state in reducer and you don’t need to use `getStateForAction()` on every screen. Good luck!